# Change styling of react components created during render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a large array of react components that are created during the render process. After they are created I want to change their styling but the things I've tried haven't effected it.

```
  render() {

    const arr= this.props.arr.map((el, i) => {
    return (
      <AA> // inserting a style here with "!important" doesn't work, classNames don't work either
        <BB/>
      </AA>
    );
    });

    return (
      <CC>
        {arr}
      </CC>
    );
  }
```

In this example I want to change the styling of the "AA" components after they have been rendered. I don't want to interfere with the components source file I just want to add or change a style after everything is said and done.

Comment: If `AA` is an external component then there is no way around to do this except passing style as a props to `AA` component and in `AA` component manually adding a style attribute with incoming props.

Comment: @Bud S. your question isn't cleared. can you explain little more about your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

try [`React.cloneElement()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)

```
const StyledAA = React.cloneElement(AA, { style: customStyleObject });
```

For the css specificity problem,
inline should always win.

if you're using StyledComponents, 
there's a way to add higher specificity like:

```
&&& { 
   style
 }
```

(n number of `&` for n number of classNames)

https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity